# Why is the coefficient of static friction used in the formula for the stopping distance when there is no relative motion between tyres and road?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, rotational-dynamics, friction, everyday-life

Instead of using the coefficient of static friction between the tyres and the road, should we not use the coefficient of kinetic friction between the brake pads and the disc?

Answer (score 1):

The static friction force between the tyres (and the rest of the car) and the road is the contact force which in part is responsible for the acceleration of a car (the system).

*. . . . the coefficient of kinetic friction between the brake pads and the discs* has no mention of external forces affecting the motion of the car (the system).

It may well be that the braking system does not produce the desired effect, ie reducing the rotational speed of the wheels sufficiently, but the frictional forces between the tyres and the road are the external forces which change the motion of the car. Just think of having good brakes whilst the car is being driven on ice.

Answer (score 0):

The friction between the brake pads and disc (called "abrasive friction), applies a torque to the wheel which, in turn, exerts a force acting forward on the road. Then, per Newton's 3rd law the road exerts and equal and opposite friction force acting backwards on the wheel. That friction force causes the vehicle to decelerate (brake). See the Figure below.

If the road friction is static, it stops the car without skidding. If the braking force is too high so that it exceeds the maximum possible static friction force, the friction is kinetic and the wheels skid.

Hope this helps.

[image]